# "io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: '[class_name]' doesn't exist in current schema", when calling realm.deleteAll () [Realm 4.1.1]

Tags: java, android, realm

I had a `RealmAssignment` class which was a part of my Realm module. After deleting it, and removing it from the module, I started getting errors when performing `realm.deleteAll()`. Here is the part of error trace:

```
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: 'RealmAssignment' doesn't exist in current schema.
   at io.realm.internal.ColumnIndices.getColumnInfo(ColumnIndices.java:112)
   at io.realm.RealmSchema.getColumnInfo(RealmSchema.java:250)
   at io.realm.ImmutableRealmSchema.get(ImmutableRealmSchema.java:41)
   at io.realm.RealmSchema.getAll(RealmSchema.java:88)
   at io.realm.BaseRealm.deleteAll(BaseRealm.java:602)
   at io.realm.Realm.deleteAll(Realm.java:135)`
```

I have searched for this error on the internet and these are the things I've tried so far:

- Disabled instant run
- Added `-keepnames public class * extends io.realm.RealmObject` to my proguard-rules.pro file
- Put `apply plugin: 'realm-android'` in app level gradle file after all other `apply plugin` calls
- Clean, rebuild, invalidate caches and restart

None of the above helped.

I initialize realm using following code:

```
new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
   .modules(new RealmDefaultModule())
   .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
   .build();
```

I have also searched entire project for any reference to "RealmAssignment" class or text containing it, but I found none.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

This is my `RealmDefaultModule` class:

```
@RealmModule(classes = {RealmCheckInVolunteerEvent.class,
        RealmCheckInLocation.class,
        RealmCheckInStaffEvent.class,
        RealmEmail.class,
        RealmInventoryItem.class,
        RealmMember.class,
        RealmMemberAssignment.class,
        RealmOrganizationalUnit.class,
        RealmShift.class,
        RealmSize.class,
        RealmSizeType.class,
        RealmSMS.class,
        RealmTimelineItem.class,
        RealmUser.class,
        RealmUserOrgUnit.class,
        RealmUserSizeType.class,
        RealmUserSize.class})
public class RealmDefaultModule {
}
```

I initialize my RealmDefaultConfiguration as a singleton, this is the whole class:

```
public class RealmDefaultConfiguration {

    private static RealmConfiguration myConfig;

    public static synchronized RealmConfiguration getInstance() {
        if (myConfig == null) {
            myConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .modules(new RealmDefaultModule())
                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                    .build();
        }
        return myConfig;
    }
}
```

(do you think this might be a problem?)

I set my default configuration to the above in my `Application` class like this:

```
Realm.init(this);
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(RealmDefaultConfiguration.getInstance());
```

And then in my `MainActivity`, I call:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.deleteAll();
            }
        });
realm.close();
```

Comment: Can you show `RealmDefaultModule`? Are you 100% sure you are using the configuration you created here?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce editted

Comment: If you have `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` it should never crash with a migration error. It sounds like a gradle cache error somewhere to me. Have you tried cleaning all gradle caches and rebuilding the app?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior I ran cleanBuildCache from gradle options, and also deleted everything inside .gradle folder in project, but I'm still getting the same error. Maybe if I force him somehow to delete realm through migration, like adding some dummy realm class or changing a field? I definitelly changed realm objects and added / deleted classes in the past and it was never a problem.

Comment: Realm is autogenerating a class called `RealmDefaultModuleMediator` based on your module. You can find it under the /build folder. Try to find that  and see if `RealmAssignment.class` is mentioned in there?

Comment: I found `DefaultRealmModuleMediator` class but there were no refferences to `RealmAssignment.class`. :( I also used FindInPath to search everywhere to any refference to that class but I've found nothing. There is a `RealmMemberAssignment.class` but that is completelly different class. (Could name similarity cause problems maybe?) I also tried adding new dummy realm class to my default module to try to trigger delete because of migration, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like the code you are compiling isn't the one running on your device for some reason.

Comment: Could you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah, I just returned the deleted class back into the module. I don't use it though, but I'm not getting any errors anymore.