# Need help understanding how to remove Realm Models from Schema

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

This has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201102/io-realm-exceptions-realmexception-class-name-doesnt-exist-in-current-sch) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070608/realm-android-io-realm-exceptions-realmexception-domainmodel-doesnt-exist)) but I have created a simple example to show how to reproduce the error.

Here is the crash I am seeing:

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: 'MySecondRealmModel' doesn't exist
>   in current schema.
>       at io.realm.internal.ColumnIndices.getColumnInfo(ColumnIndices.java:112)
>       at io.realm.RealmSchema.getColumnInfo(RealmSchema.java:250)
>       at io.realm.ImmutableRealmSchema.get(ImmutableRealmSchema.java:41)
>       at io.realm.RealmSchema.getAll(RealmSchema.java:88)
>       at io.realm.BaseRealm.deleteAll(BaseRealm.java:602)
>       at io.realm.Realm.deleteAll(Realm.java:135)

Set Up:
Create a fresh project, using Realm 4.3.3.
Add two Realm Models MyFirstRealmModel and MySecondRealmModel.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the code below, all it does is save 1 MyFirstRealmModel and 1 MySecondRealmModel.
2. Simulate some refactoring by deleting the class MySecondRealmModel.java and all code that pertains to it.
3. After deleting the MySecondRealmModel.java class, re-run the app and press the button to delete all the contents in Realm. You will get the crash listed above.

Where I am super confused is I thought the whole idea of `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` was to prevent these kinds of errors? Why is the `MySecondRealmModel.java` model sticking around? Currently the only fix I have is to completely uninstall the app.

This is my MainActivity.java before deleting MySecondRealmModel.java.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize Realm
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration.Builder realmBuilder = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmBuilder.build());

    // Set the listener that will delete everything in Realm
    findViewById(R.id.deleteButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.deleteAll();
                }
            });
            realm.close();
        }
    });

    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            // Create our dummy date.
            MyFirstRealmModel myFirstRealmModel = new MyFirstRealmModel();
            myFirstRealmModel.id = "firstId";
            myFirstRealmModel.data = "firstData";

            MySecondRealmModel mySecondRealmModel = new MySecondRealmModel();
            mySecondRealmModel.id = "firstId";
            mySecondRealmModel.data = "firstData";

            realm.insertOrUpdate(myFirstRealmModel);
            realm.insertOrUpdate(mySecondRealmModel);
        }
    });

    realm.close();
}
```

Comment: This reminds me of https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5745

Comment: Okay it's been like a week, you can try `try(DynamicRealm dynRealm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration())) { dynRealm.executeTransaction(d -> { d.deleteAll(); }) }` in the meantime

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce! That seems to do the trick. Still seems like there is a deeper underlying problem as I would have thought `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` would have solved this. But glad to have a backup plan.